# Why aws-cognito-next getServerSideAuth returns null?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, next.js, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify

I'm using the npm module  `aws-cognito-next` to implement authentication for one of my app. There the function `getServerSideAuth(context.req);` seems to not working as expected:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    // getServerSideAuth will parse the cookie
    const initialAuth = getServerSideAuth(context.req);
    return { props: { initialAuth } };
}
```

Then in the same page which is `Home` (`/pages/home.js`) I use this returned `initialAuth` as follows:

```
const Register = ( {initialAuth} ) => {
    console.log("initialAuth is: " + util.inspect(initialAuth))
    const auth = useAuth(initialAuth);
    ...
    //other logic
    ...
}
```

But I get out put as: `initialAuth is: null`. So why doesn't initialAuth isn't getting returned from serverside? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`getServerSideAuth` checks to see if user is logged in and returns tokens that can be used in `useAuth`. You can check for `null` and add logic to send the user to the login/logout pages.

```
const Register = ( {initialAuth} ) => {
  const auth = useAuth(initialAuth);
  const { login, logout } = useAuthFunctions();

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {auth ? (
        <button type="button" onClick={() => logout()}>
          sign out
        </button>
      ) : (
        <React.Fragment>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => login()}>
            sign in
          </button>
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

For more information on `useAUth` see [here](https://usehooks.com/useAuth/).